# Formatting of message in MetaMask Signature Request is off

Tags: node.js, ethereum, metamask

I'm using MetaMask to sign a nonce in order to do server side authentication. Everything works as expected expect that the message shown in the MetaMask window are cryptic signs instead of the actual message.

This is how I trigger MetaMask to sign the message (n):

```
console.log(n); //0x123456789...123456789
const sig = await web3.eth.personal.sign(n, address, "password!");
```

The result:

[image: MetaMask Signature Request]

Anyone an idea why this is happening?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, @sebastiansieber. i am actually stuck at triggering metamask to sign the message. As you are at least able to make metamask pop up, please help me in this.

Comment: you can see above how I trigger MetaMask to sign the message, not sure how I can help you without further details

Comment: Are you using locally hosted ganache or infura of other providers? Because I tried on ganache and the `personal_sign` method is not supported yet.

Comment: I use the injected web3 provider (with web3.js): const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must convert the "n" variable to HEX like this:

```
let message = web3.utils.utf8ToHex(n);
const sig = await web3.eth.personal.sign(message, address, "password!");
```

Link to documentation https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#utils-utf8tohex